# How to execute a dynamic query in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dynamicquery

I have the following query:

```
WITH modalities as (
  SELECT DISTINCT
        col4 as modalities
  FROM `myproject.table1`

SELECT 
  CONCAT("""
      SELECT 
        col1,col2, col3
        """,
      STRING_AGG( if_clauses , """,
        """), 
      """
      FROM `myproject.table1`
      GROUP BY col1,col2, col3
      ORDER BY col1,col2
      """) as query
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      CONCAT ("SUM(IF (col4 = '",tcc, "',1,0)) as ", col4) as if_clauses
    FROM contact_type )

'''
```

Basically, what it does is that it generates a query to one hot encode col4: for each modality, we generate a new column. This query returns one row with one string cell which is a query.

How can I intepret this query? I am searching for something like

```
With query as (...)
SELECT * FROM INTERPRET(QUERY)
```

Comment: You cannot do this purely in bigquery, but you can easily do this in any client of your choice! Have you considered?

Comment: Yes @MikhailBerlyant , at the moment I generate the query in job1, then I got the query as a result, and run it in job2 (I'm using python Bigquery API). It works OK but feels very, very hacky and I thought there should be a proper way to do this.

Comment: So, you are actually doing it right way!